# Saving state of inputs added by user in React

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch

I working on a small personal project using React on Rails.  I am very new to both of these things.

I have a react component that is a form. I also have another component that has some inputs that the user can add as many as needed. Using the Add Properties button.  I am trying to save the state of each input that is added.  I could have the component itself save the state but how then would I send it with my fetch post request that happens onClick?

I have looked at react's context API but cant figure out if this would help me.  Also I have never used redux so it is possible I should look into that as well.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

I understand that I don't want to reach into state.  So I was trying to figure out how to create an array of objects that will hold the input values of each input pair.  But I cannot seem to wrap my mind around how to implement.

```
  class ProductsCreate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      upc: '',
      availableOn: '',
      inputs: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.name === 'name') {
      this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
    }
    if (e.target.name === 'upc') {
      this.setState({ upc: e.target.value });
    }
    if (e.target.name === 'date') {
      this.setState({ availableOn: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  submitData = () => {
    fetch(`/send_data`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.name,
        upc: this.state.upc,
        availableOn: this.state.availableOn
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json;
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  clickHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.submitData();
  };

  appendInput = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newInput = `input-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
    this.setState({ inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([newInput]) });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form_container">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <form>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <label>UPC</label>
          <input type="text" name="upc" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <label>Availiable On</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="date"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <h1>Properties</h1>
          {this.state.inputs.map(input => (
            <Properties key={input} />
          ))}
          <button onClick={this.appendInput}>Add Properties</button>
          <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsCreate;
```

This is the component that will be added on click

```
import React from 'react';

class Properties extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="property_container">
        <label>Property Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="propertyName" />
        <label>Property Value</label>
        <input type="text" name="propertyValue" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Properties;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass handle change as prop to Properties component and then use that prop in input onChange within your Properties component. Make the following edits. I also suggest if you don't want to continously update the state on every character typed use debounce.

ProductsCreate

```
      {this.state.inputs.map(input => (
        <Properties key={input} onChange={this.handleChange} name={input}/>
      ))}
```

Properties

```
      <input type="text" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham !  So how do I update the state of that particular input in the array?  I have added what you suggested.  When I click add input I get an object added to the inputs array that now has empty values.
const newInput = `input-${this.state.inputs.length}: name:'', value:''`;

Comment: @binarycycle updated the answer check. I am passing the name as a prop which is an added to input a name and when input onChange will be triggered you will get the name of the input which is being updated and value of it depending on which you can update the state.